# Getting Netbeans Applet on Web Page

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, java-web-start

Okay, I am going to go through ALL my steps thus far just so that this process can be sped up hopefully. I have done this before, but it was awhile back and I forgot how, but I know it is possible.

1. I made a Neatbeans created Java Application.
   Then doing what this article said (and I rememeber doing this for the other program) I did the following:

> 1. Right-click the package containing your app and choose New | Other.
> 2. Select the Swing GUI Forms category and choose JApplet Form. (This template is one of several applet templates, but this one is the one you want to create a JApplet that you can design in the GUI Builder.)
> 3. In the editor window, select the tab for the form that you want to convert to an applet.
> 4. In the Inspector window, select the sub-components of the form and press Ctrl-C (or Ctrl-X) to copy them.
> 5. In the editor window, select the tab for the JApplet form that you have just created.
> 6. In the Inspector window, right-click the JApplet node and press Ctrl-V to paste the components.

2.After that I right-clicked my project "ConsulantsStaff" (yes it is spelled wrong) and I went to Web Start and made the following changes:
[image]

3.I then ran Clean and Build, then uploaded the files from the projects "dist" folder online. 
    The files were: ConsulantsStaff.jar, launch.html, launch.jnlp

4.I then tried to incorporate that into a HTML file, which now looks like this:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><!-- ########################## IMPORTANT NOTE ############################ --><!-- This preview HTML page will work only with JDK 6 update 10 and higher! --><!-- ###################################################################### -->
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Consulants Applet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body bgcolor="#000000">
    <h3></h3>
    <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
    var attributes = {
    code: "mypackage.consulantsstaff",
    archive: "consulantsstaff.jar",
    width: 800,
    height: 740
    };
    var parameters = {jnlp_href:"launch.jnlp"}; <!-- Applet Parameters -->
    var version = "1.5"; <!-- Required Java Version -->
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
    </script><!-- Or use the following applet element to launch the applet using jnlp_href --><!--
    <applet width="300" height="300">
    <param name="jnlp_href" value="launch.jnlp"/></applet>
    -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

So...yea, the only step I truly remember doing is step 1, the rest I am winging and so far it is not working.
The current location of this applet is here, it is just a black screen right now: [Applet](http://dawnofvengeance.com/applications/game/)

Any and all help appreciated,
-Austin
(I have this post running on two sites as I need an answer ASAP, and thank you all in advance!)

Comment: "*I have this post running on two sites"*  It is good you mentioned that.  Could you also cross-link the posts? *"as I need an answer ASAP.."*  But ***that*** was better left unsaid.  On web forums people answer when & if they feel like it.  Asking them to reply urgently is more likely to make them skip to some post that is *not* urgent - and see if someone posts an answer while they are off doing other things.  In fact, if I'd noticed that part when I 1st read the post, that is exactly what ***I*** would have done.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I add the I need an answer ASAP as a description of why I posted it in two places. I generally do not make a topic in two locations as that is a form of just "using" someone to me. Right now I am trying to accomplish multiple tasks and thus I have been checking any posts for updates nonstop, since two sites have a broader range of people than just one I posted twice, and I noted it out of respect for each other with the description/mindset of...YES, I kind of need to solve this while my mind is fresh on the issue right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)
...
    at javax.swing.JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.java:372)
    at consulantsstaff.UpdateUser.initComponents(UpdateUser.java:48)
```

Did you call ..

```
JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
```

..on line 48 of `UpdateUser`?  That is my best guess.  Even a trusted applet is not allowed to exit the VM (or to create a frame that does the same).

BTW - you really should have figured this out before getting to 44 Kb of signed code!

---

Perhaps this app. actually needs to be a `JFrame` based app. that is launched from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (for many reasons, including that a *sand-boxed* ***frame*** launched using JWS can make that method call without problems).

Comment: Well it runs on my environment fine, and it finished clean and successful. I am also using the code above merely as a test before I upload the real project I am turning into an applet. I just do not wish to accidentally mess up the important project.
But as far as everything else goes, does it look right/ok?
And I thought I am doing webstart? And that webstart requires an applet to even run in a html document.

Comment: *"does it look right/ok?"*  It looks like what I saw in the console - I did not proceed further.  I downloaded the JNLP & set a codebase, removed the `all-permissions` declaration, downloaded the Jar, renamed it to `zip` opened it and stripped out the `MANIFEST-MF`, renamed it to back to `jar` & ran it from the command line.  I mean come on, seriously:  Do you think I can risk running trusted code 1) which is already known to be broken 2) written by a newbie 3) who is a complete stranger?  You've got hopes!  (But I hope you also appreciate the trouble I went to, in order to offer assistance.)

Comment: Ok now I am very confused, I am not asking you download the the file and run it. I am asking if the way I am trying to run it online will work, is done properly. Mostly, the part of how my Web Start is setup and how the HTML javascript part is written.

Yes I am a newb, no I am not asking you download my crap code and try to run it on your environment, I just want it to run on the web as an applet, and you do not have to help me if you'd rather not.
And I greatly appreciate any/all help I ever receive on forums.

Comment: *"I am asking if the way I am trying to run it online will work"* I am not in a position to run JNLP/applet based code on-line at the moment so I am unable to test that directly. *"is done properly."* Not half.  1) Start with the exception I already mentioned. 2) The HTML is invalid.  Check it in a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/). 3) The JNLP is invalid.  Check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/)  That is about all I can tell from my examination so far.